# How do I make this element appear as it should in this code?

Tags: css, html, xhtml, html-email

I a making an HTML email, and I have most of the elements appear as they should. But for some reason, one element I am trying to insert, a small box with an address and a contact doesn't show up like it should.[image: Screencap of file]

That grey bar at the bottom with the address should appear the same width as the main white box, and should be surrounded by blue.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>BigParser</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <!--main background color, size, etc.-->
      <tr bgcolor= "#21A1EC">
        <td align="center" style="padding: 40px 0 30px 0;">
          <!--this BigParser logo at the top-->
          <img src="bigparser.gif" width="186" height="43" style="display:block;" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr bgcolor= "#21A1EC">
        <td align="center">
          <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
            <!--creates main padded content table-->
            <tr width=100% bgcolor= "#ffffff">
              <td align="center" style="padding-left: 35px; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-top: 40px; font-size: 30px;">
                <!--title formatting-->
                Lorem ipsum<!--do not delete--> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<!-- centering title fix-->
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr width="100%" bgcolor= "#ffffff">
              <td align="justify" style="padding-left: 35px; padding-bottom: 20; padding-right: 35; font-size: 23px;">
                <!--content formatting-->
                content text
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <!--this is the unsub/links box, contains the unsubscribe and links to social media-->
              <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                <tr align="center" >
                  <!--this contains unsub link and copyright-->
                  <td bgcolor="50B54D" width="60%">
                    unsub link
                  </td>
                  <td bgcolor="EC552B" width="40%">
                    social media links
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="EEEFF1" align="left" style="font-size:15;">
              <td style="padding-left:10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                BigParser | 12020 Sunrise Valley Dr, Sute 101 Reston VA 20191
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

However the address bar does appear to format correctly if i move it above the green and orange boxes, [image: HTML works when address is above]

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
            <!--creates main padded content table-->
            <tr width=100% bgcolor= "#ffffff">
              <td align="center" style="padding-left: 35px; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-top: 40px; font-size: 30px;">
                <!--title formatting-->
                Lorem ipsum<!--do not delete--> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<!-- centering title fix-->
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr width="100%" bgcolor= "#ffffff">
              <td align="justify" style="padding-left: 35px; padding-bottom: 20; padding-right: 35; font-size: 23px;">
                <!--content formatting-->
                content text
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="EEEFF1" align="left" style="font-size:15;">
              <td style="padding-left:10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                BigParser | 12020 Sunrise Valley Dr, Sute 101 Reston VA 20191
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <!--this is the unsub/links box, contains the unsubscribe and links to social media-->
              <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                <tr align="center" >
                  <!--this contains unsub link and copyright-->
                  <td bgcolor="50B54D" width="60%">
                    unsub link
                  </td>
                  <td bgcolor="EC552B" width="40%">
                    social media links
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </tr>          
          </table>
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, how do I change the code so that the address appears below the green and orange boxes, but stays the same width as the rest of the elements above it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move address row to the unsub link/social media links table and make its `colspan="2"`. I hope this is what you are asking for

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>BigParser</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <!--main background color, size, etc.-->
    <tr bgcolor="#21A1EC">
      <td align="center" style="padding: 40px 0 30px 0;">
        <!--this BigParser logo at the top-->
        <img src="bigparser.gif" width="186" height="43" style="display:block;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#21A1EC">
      <td align="center">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
          <!--creates main padded content table-->
          <tr width=100% bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <td align="center" style="padding-left: 35px; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-top: 40px; font-size: 30px;">
              <!--title formatting-->
              Lorem ipsum
              <!--do not delete-->&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
              <!-- centering title fix-->
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <td align="justify" style="padding-left: 35px; padding-bottom: 20; padding-right: 35; font-size: 23px;">
              <!--content formatting-->
              content text
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top">
            <!--this is the unsub/links box, contains the unsubscribe and links to social media-->
            <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
              <tr align="center">
                <!--this contains unsub link and copyright-->
                <td bgcolor="#50B54D" width="60%">
                  unsub link
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#EC552B" width="40%">
                  social media links
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr bgcolor="#EEEFF1" align="left" style="font-size:15;">
            <td style="padding-left:10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;" colspan="2">
              BigParser | 12020 Sunrise Valley Dr, Sute 101 Reston VA 20191
            </td>
          </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Something to note: colspan doesnt work well with a few email clients.

Comment: There are a few errors in your code: You are using colors without hash in the value, your table structure is wrong for the addition you did to the code (tables cant sit inside a tr). When giving an answer try to improve on the code of the person so its easy for them in future and so they don't keep making the same mistakes.

Comment: @Syfer This is not my code. I totally agree with you and this code is not clean or optimal. I just solved his specific problem.

Comment: part of solving the issue should be fixing issues as well. maybe fix the code so its easy for the person in future please?